# yii booster - not loading property TbExtendedGridView

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I wanted to add `$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(....` this to my code but i get the following error :

> Error 500
>   Property "TbExtendedGridView.rowHtmlOptionsExpression" is not defined.

I updated to version 1.07 but is still get this error.

I would really like to know why of this error when iam using the most up to date version and when `TbGridView` is working , however on this page http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extended-grid.html it states that you can use `'fixedHeader' => true,`  with `TbGridView` but for me its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rowHtmlOptionsExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#rowHtmlOptionsExpression-detail) was introduced in Yii 1.1.13 so upgrade to this version.

Comment: i have to update yii framework ? i am using  Yii Framework v1.1.12